# Ajax with CodeIgniter - data not received on server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base+"tree/plant/",
            data:{
                name: $('#field_treename').val(),
                summary: $('#field_summary').val(),
                description: $('#field_description').val(),
                address: $('#field_url').val(),
                category: $('#field_category').val()
            }
        })
        .done(function(resp){
            $('#plant-tree-inner').html(resp);
        });
```

`base` is my base URL, `tree` is a controller and `plant` is a method in that controller.

The URL is correct, the controller and method are in place, with correct names. I've made sure of that by echoing a string in the `plant` method and it appeared correctly on the client after the AJAX response.

However, none of the post data seems to be arriving at the server.

Doing `echo $this->input->post('name');` inside the `plant` method gives an empty string. Doing `var_dump($_POST)` gives an empty array. I even tried giving parameters to the `plant` method but that just throws a `missing parameter` error.

So where is the data getting lost and why?

EDIT: I see now that my question is wrong. It has nothing to do with CodeIgniter, since the data isn't being sent at all. The field values are `undefined` according to Javascript, but they certainly exist in HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field_treename" placeholder="Tree name" value="" />
```

Comment: Check your network tab in dev tools and check if post data is being posted or not.

Comment: @TamásSzabó It seems it's not being sent. The headers are there but `post` is empty. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have a parent form?

Comment: These fields are not in a form, but I can add one if need be.

Comment: I'd try it. And edit data as data: $("yourform").serialize(); just for try

Comment: Tried it with and without `serialize`, still the same.

Comment: And if you do only with form and not ajax?

Comment: Hm. Really weird. I just tried that, and `$_POST` is still empty.

Comment: I added an edit to the question, please check.

Comment: what if you fill uot your ajax request with fixed data, instead of form values?

Comment: dont you have more of 1 input with same id?

Comment: No, these are the only fields on the whole page.

Comment: what if you write to the console this? `$('#field_treename').val()` ?

Comment: It shows "undefined".

Comment: what if simply document.getElementById("field_treename").value; ?

Comment: Same thing, I don't get it.

Comment: Isn't it in an Iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is wrong with jQuery library. 
For test' sake, [try](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to send request avoiding it.

Comment: I'm using the jQuery library hosted by them (not locally) so jQuery itself couldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am aware of that. Was asking you that check raw JS AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also..

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base+"tree/plant/",
        data:{
            name: $('#field_treename').val(),
            summary: $('#field_summary').val(),
            description: $('#field_description').val(),
            address: $('#field_url').val(),
            category: $('#field_category').val()
        }
        success:function(resp){
        $('#plant-tree-inner').html(resp);
        }
});
```

Comment: That throws a syntax error at `success:function(resp){`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simulate the problem in the very basic method like creating another directory in your localhost or server like this and create files as describe below.

in the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>POST Sending Problem</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="test(12, 'http://localhost/your_test_dir/your_phpfile.php')">Link</a>
    <script src="custom_function.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Create js file for example `test.js` and put this as test

```
function test (id, base) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'id': id
    },
    url: base,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('no data');
    }
  });

}
```

Next create a php file `your_phpfile.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  echo $_POST['id'];
} else {
  echo "no-result";
}
?>
```

This would help you determine the problem. If this works fine, try applying it using codeigniter.

Good Luck

Comment: I encounter the same problem, and the method I give you help me determine the problem

Answer (score -2):

User this one..

```
var request = "name="+$('#field_treename').val()+"&"
        request += "summary="+$('#field_summary').val()+"&"
        request += "description="+$('#field_description').val()+"&"
        request += "address="+$('#field_url').val()+"&"
        request += "category="+$('#field_category').val()
```

and in set as `data=request`. This should work.

Comment: Jquery can serialize objects